# Expand symbol getting cutoff when using shinydashboard's box function

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dashboard with a collapsible box included in it, which works great, except for some reason, when the box is collapsed, the `+` sign is cut off (see below). Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(id = "tableBox", collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = F, width = "100%", height = "100%",
        "Taco Bell is an American-based chain of fast food restaurants originating in Irvine, California in 1962, by founder Glen Bell. Taco Bell is a 
        subsidiary of Yum! Brands, Inc. The restaurants serve a variety of Mexican-inspired foods, that include: tacos, burritos, quesadillas, nachos, 
        novelty and specialty items, along with a variety of value menu items. As of 2018, Taco Bell serves over two billion customers each year, at 
        7,072 restaurants, more than 93 percent of which are owned and operated by independent franchisees and licensees.")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible fix is to change the html code that `box()` produces, search for <div class="box-header" (line 8) and modify the hight.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

box_html <- 
'<div class="col-sm-100%">
  <div class="box" style="height: 100%">
    <div class="box-header" style="height: 40px; width: 50; pxtext-align: right;border: 0;"> 
      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
          <i class="fa fa-minus" role="presentation" aria-label="minus icon" style="size:10px"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body" id="tableBox">Taco Bell is an American-based chain of fast food restaurants originating in Irvine, California in 1962, by founder Glen Bell. Taco Bell is a 
        subsidiary of Yum! Brands, Inc. The restaurants serve a variety of Mexican-inspired foods, that include: tacos, burritos, quesadillas, nachos, 
        novelty and specialty items, along with a variety of value menu items. As of 2018, Taco Bell serves over two billion customers each year, at 
        7,072 restaurants, more than 93 percent of which are owned and operated by independent franchisees and licensees.</div>
  </div>
</div>'

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        uiOutput('box')))

server <- function(input, output) { 
    
    output$box <- renderUI({
        tagList(
            HTML(box_html)
        )
        
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```